# How to stream a video on the website using python?

Tags: python, html, opencv, flask

I can't seem to be able to stream a video using my webcam on the website using python

```py
@app.route("/Record" , methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def Record():

        cv2.namedWindow("preview")
        vc = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

        if vc.isOpened(): # try to get the first frame
            rval, frame = vc.read()
        else:
            rval = False

        while rval:
            cv2.imshow("preview", frame)
            rval, frame = vc.read()
            key = cv2.waitKey(20)
            if key == 27: # exit on ESC
                break

        vc.release()
        cv2.destroyWindow("preview")
        return render_template('record.html')
```

I have tried these codes that i have found online but it only allows the video to be streamed by opening a new window. What should I do?

Answer (score -1):

You can modify you API as following,

```py
from flask import Response, render_template
import cv2

@app.route("/Record", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def Record():
    def generate_frames():
        vc = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

        if vc.isOpened():  # try to get the first frame
            rval, frame = vc.read()
        else:
            rval = False

        while rval:
            # Encode the frame into JPEG format
            rval, frame = vc.read()
            if rval:
                ret, buffer = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)
                frame = buffer.tobytes()
                yield (b'--frame\r\n'
                       b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n')
            else:
                break

    return Response(generate_frames(), mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')
```

Here, I have used `yield` for every frame and used mimetype `multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame` to return the response. Now, you can invoke this API from wherever you want and it will return you video frames. You can design separate HTML page to handle it or by directly open in chrome will also work.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the advice. It worked but is there a way to Stream it on record.html with the web design in the background?

Comment: You can create on HTML page and use javascript to invoke the API and render in HTML by adding CSS. I have not tried it but i think it will work.

Comment: You can also emit socket event an capture it in HTML and use js to render frames

Answer (score -2):

You can achieve this by using a web framework like Flask for the server-side and a combination of HTML, JavaScript, and perhaps a library like Flask-SocketIO for real-time communication.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_socketio import SocketIO
import cv2
import base64
from io import BytesIO

app = Flask(__name__)
socketio = SocketIO(app)

def video_stream():
    vc = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

    while True:
        rval, frame = vc.read()

        if rval:
            _, buffer = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)
            jpg_data = base64.b64encode(buffer).decode('utf-8')
            yield f'data:image/jpeg;base64,{jpg_data}'

@socketio.on('connect')
def handle_connect():
    socketio.emit('video_feed', video_stream())

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app)
```